# Regex to generate dynamic sql

Tags: regex, notepad++, dynamic-sql

I want to generate dynamic sql on Notepad++ based on some rules. These rules include everything, so no sql knowledge is needed, and are the following:

1. Dynamic sql must have each single quote escaped by another single quote ( 'hello' becomes ''hello'')
2. Each line should begin with "+@lin"
3. If a line has only whitespace, nothing should be following the "+@lin", despite following rules
4. Replace each \t directly following "+@lin" with "+@tab"
5. Add " +' " after the @lin/@tab sequence
6. Add a single quote at the end of line

So, as an example, this input:

```
select 1,'hello'
from        --two tabs exist after from

    table1
```

should become:

```
+@lin+'select 1,''hello'''
+@lin+'from     --two tabs exist after from'
+@lin
+@lin+@tab+'table1'
```

What I have for now is the following 4 steps:

- Replace single quote with double quotes to cover rule 1
- Replace `^(\t*)(.*)$` with `\+@lin\1\+'\2'` to cover rules 2,5,6
- Replace `\t` with `\+@tab` to cover rule 4
- Replace `(\+@tab)*\+''$` with nothing to cover rule 3

Notice that this mostly works, except for the third replacement, which replaces all tabs, and not only the ones at the beginning. I tried `(?<=^\t*)\t` with no success- it matches nothing.

I'm looking for a solution which satisfies the rules in as few replacement steps as possible.

Comment: Can you have more than 1 TAB at the beginning of line?

Comment: Yes, multiple tabs are possible

Comment: so output is `+@lin+@tab+@tab+'table1'` for 2 TABs?

Comment: @Toto yes,correct. Seems example was a bit poor...

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After replacing single quotes with 2 quotes, you can do the rest in a single step:

Not very elegant for processing multiple TABs, but it works.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:(\t)(\t)?(\t)?(\t)?(\t)?(\S.*)|\h*|(.+))$`
- Replace with: `+@lin(?1+@tab+(?2@tab+)(?3@tab+)(?4@tab+)(?5@tab+)'$6')(?7+'$7')`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       # beginning of line
    (?:     # non capture group
        (\t)    # group 1, tabulation
        (\t)?   # group 2, tabulation, optional
        (\t)?   # group 3, tabulation, optional
        (\t)?   # group 4, tabulation, optional
        (\t)?   # group 5, tabulation, optional
        (\S.*)  # group 6, a non-space character followed by 0 or more any character but newline
      |       # OR
        \h*     # 0 or more horizontal spaces
      |       # OR
        (.+)    # group 7, 1 or more any character but newline
    )       # end group
$       # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
+@lin       # literally
(?1         # if group 1 exists
    +@tab+      # add this
    (?2@tab+)   # if group 2 exists, add a second @tab+
    (?3@tab+)   #   id
    (?4@tab+)   #   id
    (?5@tab+)   #   id
    '$6'        # content of group 6 with single quotes
)           # endif
(?7         # if group 7 exists
    +           # plus sign
    '$7'        # content of group 3 with single quotes
)           # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use three substitutions here, it is not quite possible (without additional assumptions) to reduce the number of steps here since you need to replace at the same positions.

**Step 1:** Replace single quotes with double - `'` with `''`. No regex so far, but you can have the regex checkbox on.

**Step 2**: Add `+@lin+` at the start of the line and only wrap its contents with `'` if there is any non-whitespace char on the line (while keeping all TABs before the first `'`):

*Find What*: `^(\t*+)(\h*\S)?+(.*)`
*Replace With*: `+@lin+$1(?2'$2$3':)`

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\t*+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): zero or more TABs
- `(\h*\S)?+` - Group 2 (`$2`): an optional sequence of any zero or more horizontal whitespace chars and then a non-whitespace char
- `(.*)` - Group 3 (`$3`): the rest of the line
- `+@lin+$1(?2'$2$3':)` - replaces the match with `+@lin+` + Group 1 value (i.e. tabs found), and then - only if Group 2 matches - `'` + Group 2 + Group 3 values + `'`

**Step 3**: Replace each TAB after `+@lin+` with `@tab+`:

*Find What*: `(\G(?!^)|^\+@lin\+)\t` 
*Replace With*: `$1@tab+`

*Details*:

- `(\G(?!^)|^\+@lin\+)` - Group 1: either

  - `\G(?!^)` - end of the previous match
  - `|` - or
  - `^\+@lin\+` - start of a line and `+@lin+` string
- `\t` - a TAB char.

The replacement is the concatenation of Group 1 value and `@tab+` string.

See [this regex online demo](https://regex101.com/r/al5cqv/1).

Comment: Was hard to choose, I chose convenience over elegance. Thanks for the alternative though, and I guess the two answers together "prove" it can't be done in one step.